# How to preserve NoData areas when changing data type in GeoTiff with QGIS or gdal_translate?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, nodata

I have a float geotiff raster with values 0, 1 and 2, along with a nodata area.  I'm trying to convert the file type do Byte but I'm not being able to preserve the nodata area. It gets converted to 0 and mixed with the data.

Here is the *gdal_info* of the source dataset

```
(output from gdalinfo clipped...) 
Center      ( -50.5000000, -14.0000000) ( 50d30' 0.00"W, 14d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=4701x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
```

I then run:
`gdal_translate -ot Byte teste.tif output.tif`

The NoData value gets preserved, as gdalinfo returns

```
(output from gdalinfo cliped...)
Center      ( -50.5000000, -14.0000000) ( 50d30' 0.00"W, 14d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=4701x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
```

But looking at the image in QGis shows that the nodata area was transformed to 0

Here is the original raster in Float64 format
[image: Original raster in Float64 format]

And here is what I get after `gdal_translate`
[image]

I'm using GDAL 2.2.2 in Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure your QGIS display settings aren't the culprit? I.e. nodata is set to a different color than 0?

Comment: I'm sure. When I click outside the map, I get value 0 instead of NoData. Meanwhile, I solved my immediate problem using gdalwarp and gdal_edit instead of QGis transform and raster calculator